# How to convert Vector3 to Quaternion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to figure out how to convert a Vector3 to a Quaternion. Also will it be OK if I need to constantly update said value?

Comment: never use quaternions for any reason.  You cannot use, access or set them, they are not available.  Simply use **Rotate**, **RotateAround** and if you like simply set the **eulerAngles** or maybe **localEulerAngles**.

Comment: Quaternion.Euler()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User controlled Quaternion Slerp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724786/user-controlled-quaternion-slerp)

Comment: @JoeBlow Do any of those compare to localRotation? I need to the quaternions because I need the localRotation.

Comment: no offense, but maybe do a bit research yourself and look at the documentation? it should get clear immediatly ...

Comment: hi @Sie . Yes, very much.  Glance at the documentation for Transform.Rotate you will see the first thing it explains is that you can choose local or world reference.  Regarding "localEulerAngles" you will note that the word "local" is included in the actual name of the function.

Answer (score 9):

You can quite easily convert a Vector3 to a quaternion by using, for example, this:

```
Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(v.x, v.y, v.z);
```

So, for example, that's

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(V3.x, V3.y, V3.z);
```

That should do it!

Comment: Well @JoeBlow is having me question whether using quaternions is the best way as they can't be updated apparently.

Comment: Quaternions are rather complex, that's mostly why. Have a look at the docs to see their main uses: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html